# Working on Console.Write String Formatting with

Tags: c#, arrays, client-server, string-formatting

I'm currently working on this sample code of mine wherein I want to display an array of numbers coming from the server to the client screen.

Basically, I first make the server create an array of 99 randomly generated numbers who's values are from 1 - 100, convert the array into a string and then transport the string to the server using Byte sending.

The code looks like:

```
//SERVER
int[] result = GenerateNumbers();
string resultingString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
     resultingString = resultingString + result[i] + ",";
s.Send(asen.GetBytes(resultingString));

//CLIENT
byte[] bb = new byte[1000];
int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 1000);

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
     Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
}
```

Now what I want to do is to show the resulting array in the client screen. My code currently can do that. However, with the `Console.Write()` command, it continuously displays the string until it ends. As in the below example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 ... 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

What I want to do now is to make the display formatted like this:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23  . . . . . . . . . . 
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

Can someone please point me to a good way to do this? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft.aspx) is what you're after - this'll pad the left hand side of a given string to make it n characters long, using the padding character of your choosing.

To break every nth number you need (after your Console.Write(...);):

```
if((i % n) == 0) {
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! but what about the breaks? I want to break the string writing after every 20th number.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your client. You are sending a comma separated string and I don't see you handling that.
I assumed that UTF8 was used.
I hope this helps:

```
//CLIENT
//Makes an array to hold stream content
var bb = new byte[stm.Length];
//Fill the array with the stream content
stm.Read(bb, 0, (int)stm.Length);
//Converts the array of bytes back to a string
var rcvString = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bb);
//Split the string into an array using "," as separator
var array = rcvString.Split(new string[]{","}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var pad = 2;   
var inc = 20;
var max = array.Length;
//Iterates through the array in "inc" intervals                        
for (var i = 0; i < max; i+=inc)
{
    //Iterates through a section of the array determined by "i" and "inc" 
    //(there is a special case if "inc" it's not a multiple of max)
    for (var j = 0; j < (max - i > inc ? inc : max - i); j += 1)
    {
        Console.Write(String.Format(@" {0}",array[i + j].PadLeft(pad)));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Very complete :) you could changed the \n Write to a Console.WriteLine? Or a Environment.NewLine?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Console.WriteLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to break to the new line on the appropriate value..